# COUNTIF with partial criteria doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use simple formula with Countif and the criteria is partial text
Example: say the range is `A25:A32`

```
10060019
10060020
10060021
10060022
10060023
10060024
10060025
10060026
```

And when I used this formula

`=COUNTIF(A25:A32,"*" & 1006 & "*")`

**I got 0..** And that's weird for me as this was working for me before.

I am using **Office 365 32 Bit**.

Is there a bug in that version .. or what?

Comment: It does not work with numbers. You will need to bracket with `<` and `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Range `A25:A32` has Number format , use this formula istead : `=COUNTIF(A25:A32,">" & 1006)` .
otherwise you should renew `A25:A32` values to Text format to use formula : `=COUNTIF(A25:A32,"*1006*")`

Comment: I have other numbers that starts with 1008 and 1009. Using greater than causes a problem in that case ..

Comment: you can use `COUNTIFS()` like this : `=COUNTIFS(A25:A32;">" & 10060000;A25:A32;"<" & 10070000)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it will be better to format the data as text not as number to keep the existing formulas.. Thanks a lot for the great help.

Comment: Attantion if there is for example 10081006 this answer will count the Number.
You can use ```=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A25:A32,4)="1006"))``` to count only the 1006 on the beginning

Comment: @YasserKhalil Yes, that will be better, you have to enter values in text format first, for doing this you can insert a new blank column (Column X) with text format then write this formula in first cell `=TEXT(A25;"0")` and copy fill down to get all numbers as Text. now you can Copy-PasteSpecial(only values) from range `X25:X32` to `A25:A32` and then use your formula.